# How to suppress current spikes in transistor feedback loop

Tags: mosfet, bjt, ltspice, feedback, transient-suppression

I am trying to pulse a load with a small constant current pulse (2mA @ 500us). The load does unfortunately have an unknown capacitance in the range 10nF - 1uF, parallel with an unknown resistance varying from 0.5-5kOhm. The current pulse should be constant over a resistor in series with the load, and not deviate more than 2%.

The circuit is powered by a single 3V cell, and will have the L8410 to generate sufficient voltage for the current pulses. An AVR Attiny will control the pulse duration and timing.

I have tested a number of different designs to see if they meet my requirements (current mirror, transistor feedback loops, opamp loops, IC's as LT3092), but they all suffer from large current spikes when pulsing the load.

The circuit design I have found to be best so far is a feedback loop between a MOSFET (M1) and BJT (Q2) transistor, where a second BJT (Q1) is used as a voltage controlled resistor from a LP-filtered PWM input (V5) to adjust the setpoint for Q2. See the LTspice schematics below.

[image: MOSFET - BJT feedback loop]

The idea is to use the fast dynamics of the M1-Q2 analog regulation to handle the edges from the switch, while the MCU-Q1 in a loop with an current sensing opamp (not in schematics) will adjust the output to have an average at 2mA in the end. The switch is implemented using Vishay DG4053A (~100ohm ON resistance, ~100ns switch time).

The problem is that I get very large current spikes as in the simulation below (current trough Rtest in lowest pane).

[image: MOSFET - BJT feedback loop. Simulation]

My question is how to suppress/eliminate the spikes in this design. I would also be very grateful for any suggestions for a better design than the one I have proposed if that would help on the problem. The circuit must run on a 3V cell coin, which is the only limitation except the pulse spec and load characteristics.

Comment: Are you sure the load is floating?

Comment: Absolutely, the load have a single input and output and is completely isolated

Answer (score 2):

I gave up dealing with transistor capacitances and found a much easier way to solve the problem:

[image: Load regulation using OPAMP LTC6255]

The circuit works by a very simple feedback loop: The current through the load is measured over Rshunt and fed back to the opamp as I*Rshunt, and thus regulating the output voltage. The LTC6255 is a good match for this application as it has limited slewrate (1.8V/us), and is therefore less prone to overshoot at rising edge.

[image: Load regulation simulation]

Perhaps this can help others with the need for fast regulation of capacitive loads with small currents. Note that the rising edge will due to the limited slewrate have a lower slope when the load goes more resistive, as a higher voltage is demanded at the output. Replacing Rshunt with a PWM driven BJT will provide the same control of reference as with Q1 in the first schematics.

Comment: Realized that I'm using a 12V rail on a 5.5V maximum rated opamp. A similar opamp with higher voltage ratings must be used to avoid smoking the poor thing (if the load is not small enough).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the MOSFET - it will have a significant drain-source capacitance and this, when you activate the switch will give you a pulse of current. You are seeing a peak current of about 15mA (according to the Rtest graph) and when you add up the 400 ohms, the 50 ohms and the analogue switch (100 ohms) and divide this into 10 volts (your supply), you get a current of 18mA. Given that Q2 "loses" about 0.7V when conducting, the current is going to be more like: -

\$ I = \dfrac{10 - 0.7}{550} = 17mA\$

I think this is your problem. Avoid using a MOSFET - use a BJT instead. Maybe use a small inductor in series but watch out for resonance issues?

Comment: Well I have tried all the standard BJT's in the LTspice lib without any improvement. The MOSFET gives a rectangular spike of 270 ns duration, while the BJT has a spike with a RC discharge curve that lasts for 600 ns. Half of the peak amplitude may be removed with an inductor before significant resonance, but this is still far above the target on 1% max overshoot.